# Thread Looper Handler

Tags: android, handler, looper

```
Thread = Worked Thread (not a main Thread/ UI Thread)
Looper.prepare(); = Attached MessageQueue with worker Thread
```

That MessageQueue only assigned with Main Thread now it also available with Worker Thread with the help of Looper

```
Looper.loop(); = start process message Queue

//Handler handler (somewhere declared globally)

handler = new Handler(); //attached handler to looper

handler instance will be use to post Message/Runnable in MessageQueue
```

My question is that then what is the significance of

```
public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg);
```

Why I override it ????

Comment: What? You override it and ask us why you did it?

Comment: I attached Handler to Looper in either of the two ways, mHandler = new android.os.Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
    }
};  OR mHandler = new android.os.Handler(); What's the difference between them ???

Comment: in the first case you can send Messages and post Runnables, in the second case you can only post Runnables